# Longtable - How to use it within a table environment?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have the following latex code. My issue is that the table below does not fit the page. I would like to break the table on the "Panel C" row but I couldn't figure out how to do it while keeping the title and caption.

I tried the `longtable` package with no success.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=\parindent,tableposition=top]{caption}
    \usepackage{longtable}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=23mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]                            
      \centering                            
      \caption{Title ...}
      \caption*{Some description here } 
      \begin{tabular}{llcccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A:}                                                                                        \\ \hline
          &  & Dummy                     &                      & Dummy                     & Dummy                     \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B}                                                                                         \\ \hline
          &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Dummy} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Dummy} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Dummy} \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel C}                                                                                         \\ \hline
          &  & Dummy                     &                      & Dummy                     & Dummy                     \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}


    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need the `table` environment`. Just use `\caption` and `\label` inside of `\begin{longtable}{llll}` etc. By the way: The document misses `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, not `\end document`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `longtable` is meant for pagebreaking, a floating table feature is not really useful here.

`longtable` is basically used like `tabular`, with column descriptions, additionally it allows for `\caption` inside of the `longtable` environment.

Page breaks can be forced with an 'ordinary' `\newpage` or prevented with `\nopagebreak` or `\\*`

I've used `\newpage` right before the `Panel C` table.

Since there's no real table header, I've omitted `\endfirsthead` etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=\parindent,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
 \geometry{
   a4paper,
   total={210mm,297mm},
   left=20mm,
   right=20mm,
   top=23mm,
   bottom=30mm,
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll*{4}c}
  \caption{Title ...} \label{paneltable} \tabularnewline
  \caption*{Some description here} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A:}                                                                                        \\ \hline
          &  & Dummy                     &                      & Dummy                     & Dummy                     \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B}                                                                                         \\ \hline
          &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Dummy} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Dummy} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Dummy} \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\    \hline
    \newpage
    \caption*{Table \ref{paneltable} continued} \tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel C}                                                                                         \\ \hline
          &  & Dummy                     &                      & Dummy                     & Dummy                     \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\
    Dummy &  & 1                         &                      & 1                         & 1                         \\ \hline

    \end{longtable}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue is that I want to keep using the \caption*{Some description here }, to write a caption for my table in line with what I have done with my other tables on the document.

Comment: @volcompt: Yes, where's the problem?

Comment: On your code above, you included: "%  \caption*{Some description here } ", as a comment. If tou remove the "%" symbol the code no longer compiles correctly.

Comment: @volcompt: Uncommented: It wasn't clear from your post that `\caption*` is important

Comment: perfect. Thank you for your help. Quick question, is it possible to include a line above "Panel C" saying "Table 1 - Continued"?

Comment: @volcompt: Yes, see my update please